# copy several textboxes data into target textbox calling same function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have several input textboxes with different id and class name.  I want to track changes in any of the input textboxes, and reflect it into target textbox, but don't want to replicate the function for every individual textbox.  Is it possible to use one function for all?

Appreciate your help

Comment: What do you mean by "track changes in any of the input textboxes". Do you want this to happen on keypress of every textbox?

Comment: i want this happen on change().  i want to copy value of the textbox that user makes changes, or adds value to it.

Comment: i want this happen on change(). i want to copy the value of changed input_textbox into target_textbox after the user clicked away from the input textbox (blur()?).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..........

```
  var finalValue ='';  

$('.textBoxesId').each(function(){
     $(this).change(function(){
       finalValue  = $(this).val();

    });
 });
   $('#targetID').val(finalValue  );
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek, but each textbox has different id. so i want to know which textbox changed.

Comment: according to question,your requirement is to append the value of changed textbox value in target textbox not to know which textbox value is being changed

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the change event for all the textboxes in the page using

```
$("input:text").change(function(){
    var textValue = this.value;
    $("#targetbox").val(textValue);
});
```

If the textboxes are inside a particular container then you can limit the search inside the container

```
$("#parentcontainer input:text").change(function(){
    var textValue = this.value;
    $("#targetbox").val(textValue);
});
```